# Задать Laravel и Composer определенную версию PHP

Tags: php, laravel, composer, ispmanager

На сервере имеются разные версии PHP. От 5.2 до 7.0.
По умолчанию используется (`/usr/bin/php`) 5.4. Менять, к сожалению нельзя.
Но, в папках `/opt/php<ver>/bin` лежат другие версии интерпретатора.

Так вот, вопрос в том, как заставить **Composer** и **Laravel** использовать не `/usr/bin/php`, а `/opt/php70/bin/php`?

**Larevel** не проверял, но **Composer**, как я понял, проверяет целостность самого себя, так что "исполняемый" файл не изменить. Была идея заменить первую строчку (!#/usr/bin/env php) на что то свое, но не срослось. (а может быть я что то не то там прописывал)

Два дня уже копаю интернет, но так ни чего и не нашел.

На всякий случай, панель на сервере - ISPManager. Ось - CentOS 7

Comment: Если глобально то без доступов никак, локально через соответствующий бинарник php запускаете

Comment: @Naumov, о каких доступах речь? У меня есть рут на сервере, если вы об этом

Comment: тогда зачем несколько версий на сервере, да еще и в разных папках? композером это не решается. но можно подменить ENV

Comment: @DiGiTAL, разные версии в разных папках создает ISPManager. Вообще, на сервере не один проект. Есть довольно старые, которые могут не завестись на новой версии PHP. Теперь нужно создать новый проект. Фреймворк был выбран Laravel. Соответственно, виртуалхост под новый проект будет юзать PHP7. И хочется композер и ларавел для проекта тоже  запускать от этой версии. Как то так :)

Comment: @RAMe0 я так понимаю, что веб-сервер - Apache?

Comment: @DiGiTAL, Ага. Nginx тоже есть, но отключен.

Comment: @RAMe0, и как ты собирался использовать разные версии mod_php? если для CLI можно экспортнуть PATH, где первым будет `/opt/php70/bin/php`, то для модуля я не представляю как это сделать. настраивай nginx для php-fpm под 7.0 и на апаче проксируй. хотя, сама идея мне вообще не нравится. лучше уж отдельный сервер тогда

Comment: @DiGiTAL с веб-сервером все хорошо. Все работает. Суть не в нем, а в том, как заставить композер и ларавел использовать не стандартный php, а "кастомный". Хотя, мне эта идея самому не нравится, но все же, думал, что, возможно, есть какой то вариант... Отдельный сервер - не вариант. У нас не дедик, а VDS и новую виртуалку покупать ни кто не будет ради такого :)

Comment: `phpbruw` и `docker` смотри в сторону этих решений.

Comment: @Naumov, спасибо, надо глянуть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, спустя почти 2 года, снова встал этот вопрос.

В итоге, единственный выход, который я для себя нашел и который работает: заменить php "по умолчанию".

Переименовал  /usr/bin/php в  /usr/bin/php5

```
mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php5
```

Создал симлинк на опциональный PHP версии 7.2 в /usr/bin/

```
ln -s /opt/php72/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

Answer (score 0):

Запускать composer указывая нужную версию php
Например

```
/opt/php70/bin/php composer.phar <то что вам надо>
```

Команда будет выполняться в нужной версии php

Comment: Для компосера это Ок, но вот с ларавел не прокатывает, как я ответил предыдущему коменту, ларавел утилизирует компосер, который уже запускается под PHP по умолчанию.

Comment: composer.phar запускает то что вас может лежать где нибудь в /usr/local/bin/php
Чтобы он корректно стало работать есть переменная PATH когда вы выполняете команду например php то ищется этот фаил в путях указанных в PATH по порядку, и там есть /usr/local/bin

Чтобы исправить это добавьте вашу папку в PATH выше чем лежат системные папки и будет счастье
export PATH=~/opt/php70/bin/bin:$PATH например и это можно сделать чтобы всегда выполнялось

Answer (score 0):

Кусок конфига nginx для связки с PHP:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

Смекаете о чём я? :)
Настройте просто в другом хосте соединение с другой версией.
Да, да, я помню, у Вас апач, но...

Насчёт `composer` предыдущий ответчик прав. Но я бы вместо постоянного ввода добавил такие строчки в `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
alias composer70='/opt/php70/bin/php composer.phar'
alias composer52='/opt/php52/bin/php composer.phar'
```

если php у вас действительно по таким путям расположены. Ну, я суть хочу передать, там разберётесь что у Вас где.

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем то, для компосера это прокатит, но вот если пытаться запустить ларавел, он обращается к стандартному компосеру, который в свою очередь юзает стандартный PHP.

Answer (score 0):

У меня было аналогичное:

```
$laravel new posudamarket
```

Работать не хотело и ругалось на версию php. Но когда я попробовал выполнить:

```
$composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel  posudamarket
```

Все прошло без проблем.