# Composer устанавливает не соответствующие версии зависимости пакеты

Tags: composer

У меня есть вот такой простой файл `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "web-token/jwt-framework": "1.3",
        "rmccue/requests": "1.7"
    }
}
```

Пакет `web-token/jwt-framework` требует зависимости. Но
`web-token/jwt-framework` версии 1.3 не требует в зависимостях `symfony/var-dumper`. Вот ссылка на его `composer.json` [ссылка на github](https://github.com/web-token/jwt-framework/blob/v1.3.0/composer.json). Версия 2.0 и выше уже требует `symfony/var-dumper`. Вот [composer.json](https://github.com/web-token/jwt-framework/blob/v2.1/composer.json).

Дело в том, что у меня старый php и пакет `symfony/var-dumper` все крашит. 
Вопрос, почему я указал в зависимости `web-token/jwt-framework`версии 1.3, а composer тянет пакеты для более новой версии? Кэш композера чистил, не помогло. Удалял composer.lock file - не помогло. Проблема обнаружилась после деплоя, который запускает команду `composer install`

Comment: Посмотрите: [Задать Laravel и Composer определенную версию PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583290/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-laravel-%d0%b8-composer-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8e-php)

Comment: @Coder Спасибо, но, вы уверены что это о том? У меня проблема в том, что я указываю конкретную версию пакета, она в свою очередь имеет зависимости. А компосер мне тянет зависимости, как будто у меня самая последняя версия этого пакета. Конкретнее `web-token/jwt-framework` в версии 2.0 имеет зависимость `symfony/var-dumper`. В версии 1.3 - не имеет такой зависимости. Но почему-то все равно ее тянет! Почему? Вот в чем вопрос.

Comment: Пожалуйста) - Вы же сами написали, что у Вас старая версия php - вот и пропишите композеру, чтобы брал для этой версии. Так себе думаю.

Comment: @Coder а как композер по версии пхп определяет какие пакеты ему ставить? Это мне кажется странным. Разве он не заглядывает в файл `composer.json` и не смотрит, какие там зависимости, а потом не поступает так же для зависимостей и так далее до конца дерева зависимостей? Мне кажется это логичным. Что я упускаю?

Comment: Конечно, логично - почему тогда не работает?
Для этого нужно указать версию php в параметре platform в файле composer.json.

"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.6"
    }
 }

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую завтра это сделать. То что вдруг перестало работать - это очень странно. Я зашел на гитхаб web-token/jwt-framework и увидел у них недавние коммиты. Но у меня то стоит в файле composer.json старая версия пакета, следовательно, со старыми зависимостями. И она всегда работала. А тут - бам! И все

Comment: Удачи Вам! - думается, что получится у Вас - поскольку сomposer есть менеджер пакетов для php, то от него он и танцует, а по умолчанию берет свежее все.

Comment: @Coder спасибо! Я отпишусь, если заведется, то помечу ответ как верный)

Comment: Пожалуйста, хорошо)

Answer (score 1):

Файл `composer.json`

Для этого нужно указать версию `php` в параметре `platform` в файле `composer.json`.

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.6"
    }
 }
```

Comment: К сожалению, это решение оказалось не рабочим. При вызове команды `composer install` я получаю сообщение об ошибке, говорящее о том, что минимальная возможная версия пхп для данного пакета 7.1.

Comment: Ну, тогда, думается, иного решения нет - либо переделывать под новую версию php, или пользоваться старыми сборками. А это решение единственное) - просто, Вы хотите использовать то, что использовать в этих условиях не предназначается.

Comment: Ну да, видимо, без вариантов. Спасибо все равно!

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak  )Пожалуйста